# Derive $\dim(W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

> How to get $\dim(W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3)$?

***-edit-***

$W_1=\{(x,y,z)|x+y-z=0\}$

$W_2=\{(x,y,z)|3x+y-2z=0\}$

$W_3=\{(x,y,z)|x-7y+3z=0\}$

Comment: No, your formula is not correct. What happens if $W_1 = W_2 = W_3$?

Comment: I can guess from context, but you should tell us exactly what the $W_i$ are.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. I've edited the question.

Comment: Consider three different lines going through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for a counterexample of your guess.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments your formular is false. In your case it holds that $W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3=\{(0,0,0)\}$, so dim($W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3)=$dim$(\{(0,0,0)\})= 0$.

Comment: dim$(W_1+W_2)\leq dim(\mathbb{R}^3)=3$. So dim$(W_1+W_2)=4$ isn't even possible here. What makes you think that?

Comment: $x+y-z=0 \implies z=x+y$. So, $W_1=(x,y,x+y) \implies x(1,0,1)+y(0,1,1)$. Since $(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ are linearly independent, so they form basis, dim$W_1=2$. Similarly, basis for $W_2$ are $(1,-3,0),(0,2,1)$ and dim$W_2=2$. So, $$W_1+W_2=(x,y,x+y)+(x,-3x+2z,z) \implies (2x,-3x+y+2z,x+y+z)= x(2,-3,1)+y(0,1,1)+z(0,2,1).$$ Since, $(2,-3,1),(0,1,1),(0,2,1)$ are linearly independent, so dim($W_1+W_2$)$=3$. Is this correct now?

Comment: Yes that's right. You just have some notational errors. For example you mean $W_1=\{(x,y,x+y)\mid x,y\in \Bbb{R}\}$ (assuming that your vector spaces are $\Bbb{R}$-vectorspaces).